# Why am i getting a syntax error on my if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

```
if ({ $('#Container,#NextContainer').show()
else (var t < 20);
});
```

I keep getting a syntax error, and I've tried moving and adding brackets and parentheses till I'm crazy. Whats wrong here?

Comment: You're getting a syntax error as your if statement block is completely incorrect. I can't even figure out what condition you're trying to test from it, so I'll just link you to a guide on what it should look like: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: because usage of object is in the code is invalid.

Comment: Hard to say what you want to achieve, but a blind guess: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/rgqscnvL/)

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says the whole syntax is incorrect. You wanna do something like.

```
if (condition) {
 //if it matches the condition do this
} else {
 //if it doesn't matches the condition do this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected and syntax would be-

```
if(<your condition>)
{ 
   $('#Container,#NextContainer').show();
}
else 
   var t < 20;
```

> If you have single line(statement) inside if/else block you can skip the open and end curly braces {} like I have written in else block.If you do write multiple statements without having {} if/else would always execute the first statement.